# Is it safe to run a GUI program as another user?

Tags: xorg, security, sudo, users

I need to run a program (`libreoffice`) as another user. I noticed that the program started in the background when invoked as `kdesudo -u otheruser libreoffice`, possibly to avoid social engineering attacks.

(in the below text, "logged-in user" refers to me, not "otheruser")

- Is it safe to run an untrusted program in this way?
- Does it affect the current logged-in user? (file and process access in the context of the logged-in user)

Denial of Service attacks by fork-bombs, using excess CPU, etc. are excluded since those can occur too if I login directly on `otheruser`. For clarity, I'm looking for differences between running programs in *directly* when logged in as `otheruser` and running programs using `kdesudo`, `gksudo` and `sudo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For security purposes, assume that programs that have access to your X display can do whatever they want, including snooping on your clipboard, sending fake keystrokes to another application and other non-niceties. X just wasn't designed with isolation in mind.

For the curious or paranoid, read [Secure Linux Desktop](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4136/secure-linux-desktop) and [Passive and active attacks via X11. Is Wayland any better?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3589/passive-and-active-attacks-via-x11-is-wayland-any-better). For the extremely paranoid, check out [Qubes](https://www.qubes-os.org/), which is based on virtualized Linux instances, each running its own X server.

If you're concerned about running untrusted X applications, you must run them on a separate X display, in addition to running them as a different user (or better, in a different (virtual) machine). You can run a separate X server and display it in a nested X window in various ways: through a virtual machine ([VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox), [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware), …), with a remote X server such as [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC) which you just happen to connect to locally, or with a special-purpose X-in-X program such as [Xnest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xnest) or [Xephyr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr).

If you're concerned about social engineering attacks, that's a different problem. Social engineering targets the user; the only way to avoid them is to leave the user out.

Comment: Those security.SE questions are interesting. A virtual / other machine defeats the use of the same system: using already installed applications and settings. Social engineering is not my concern since I'm very conscious about security. From your answer, I deduce that any application ran using `kdesudo` or `gksu` is unsafe because X is shared, but doesn't that imply that using `kdesudo` for running as the other user is quite useless?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Running as another user protects against attacks that don't use X as a vector. Depending on how paranoid you are, that's either useless or better than nothing.

Comment: is it possible that my passphrase input gets captured when entering it in a `kdesudo` dialog? Or that my Firefox session gets captured? Just for clarifications, because your answer suggest so.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Yes, it's possible if you allow a rogue application to run on the same X server. [Joanna Rutkowska's blog article](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.com/2011/04/linux-security-circus-on-gui-isolation.html) explains one way.